# how to convert any string formatted date to datetime variable.?

Tags: asp.net, datetime-format

```
domaindate.Text="31-03-3015";

DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(domaindate.Text);

int day = dt.Day;
int month = dt.Month;
int year = dt.Year;
if (ddlyear.SelectedItem.Text == "1")
    {
        year = year + 1;
        month = month - 1;
        edate = String.Join("/", day, month, year);

     }

p.expirydate = Convert.ToDateTime(edate);
```

Where p.expiredate id DateTime Property variable.

```
Geting Error:String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

So, How i convert it to dd/MM/yyyy.?

Comment: please every body check questoin  first , and check your solution too..

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ParseExcact` Method with the string format.

```
  p.expirydate =DateTime.ParseExact(edate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

EDIT:

If you want add days to a specific date use the [AddDays()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method

```
DateTime dt= DateTime.Parse(domaindate.Text);
p.expirydate = today.AddDays(number of days you want);
```

Comment: i was already use it , it getting ,Error:String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: could you inspect your edate variable while debugging ?

Comment: 31/02/2016 is a wrong date bro. that's why you have an error

Comment: why wrong , do you check code in question , its right.

Comment: in your code you r doing month-1. so 3-1 =2 but you forgot the day number

Comment: hmmm, so i should put condition for every leap year AND on Feb month......, ok bro thanks, can u give me simple demo for that condition.?

Comment: i solved it, Ex.  p.expirydate = dt.AddMonths(Convert.ToInt32(ddlyear.SelectedItem.Text)*12-1);